# Adding 2d sprite in 3d environment

Tags: image

I would like to add 2d images (like grass, leaves), but where i want. Tutorials on youtube doesn't show that (or i can't find the one i want). I would like to choose where i want a particular image and fix it to my 3d model.

For example in my case i have a wooden bridge and i would like to make some grass hanging from it but i want it to be 2d sprites cause i don't need to have that in 3d.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: @MrZak Lol, not related at all bro

Comment: Of course it won't be, you should give enough information if you want to get a help.

Comment: @MrZak Bruh, i got help, you downvoted cause you can't understand a question. Someone else helped me without being as arrogant as you...

Comment: Why do you think it was me downvoting ? I'm not the only one on site having this possibility. I would be careful with such words like "arrogant" without any real reason. The point is that your question isn't clear enough. If you got help then accept the given answer to show that it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

In your “User Preferences” enable the “Import Images as Planes” add on.

Press Shift + A select "Mesh" then select Images as planes from the drop down menu. Import your image/Sprite (Check “Use Alpha” if applicable).

In “Edit Mode” select a vertex where you want to add your sprite/grass > Shift + S select “Cursor to selected. > In “Object Mode” select the plane/image you imported by clicking on it > Shift + S select “Selection to Cursor.

Nodes for alpha channel:
[image]

Comment: So i tried that and how do i make the plane invisible? also i imported a png so it's all black everywhere around the image.

Comment: Updated my answer to address this.